# How to only allow '0's and '1's to be put into a textbox in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In my windows app there is a textfield to input numbers(binary 1 or 0) for users. I'm building this app to convert binary numbers into decimal. Now What I want is , when user enter a binary number in textfield, other numbers should disable, or should give an error message. help me with this. thanx.!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook into the `KeyUp` event of the `TextBox` and check if the key is 0 or 1. If not, simply delete it.

Comment: thanx. I'm new to windows phone dev.  could you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: What if someone pastes the value into textbox? Wouldn't handling TextChanged event be more appropriate!

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone 8 - Silverlight Application.

Hook to your Textbox's KeyDown Event;

```
private void yourTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
     // Check for 1 & 0
     if ((e.PlatformKeyCode != 48) || (e.PlatformKeyCode != 49) || (e.PlatformKeyCode != 8))
     { e.Handled = true; }
}
```

Don't forget to set you Textbox's `InputScope="Number"` in XAML.